# Download tool to keep multiple ISOs up to date

Tags: bash, rsync, curl, wget

I currently use this script (https://gist.github.com/Phill93/3c2b3503810a71bb98d6edb950d7aab2) to keep my ISO collection up to date. I use it to download ISOs via Rsync or HTTP/S. Now I would like to have a better solution that can check the checksums for HTTP/S downloads and that makes URL management easier.

My goal is to have as few dependencies as possible since the script is on a USB drive and is used on different PCs.
Before I start programming something myself I wanted to ask if anyone here has an idea for something ready-made.

Comment: Ubuntu provides files for `zsync` which can manage incremental upgrading of the daily isofiles during the development and testing phase of the versions. I think it is better than using `rsync` (which can also be used for incremental upgrading), but I don't know how common it is that there are zsync files. See for example [this link](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/446/builds/278105/downloads), where `zsync` files are available alongside using `rsync` like you already do.

Comment: Instead of running 'the whole script', you could make a menu and upgrade only the iso file that you want and have time to test 'right now'. Maybe have an option to select one or more files, for example using `dialog` or `zenity` menus.

Comment: zsync automatically does the checksum. And it only downloads changes. I even use it when Ubuntu is released by renaming file to release name. If my download of daily live is near release time, the copy & down load of the release may have no change. My Kubuntu zsync:  `zsync http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/daily-live/current/mantic-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync` Note same file name as Ubuntu, but different source.